# Docker instance of Gitlab EE Initial Configuration will not start

Tags: docker, gitlab

My system is running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056, Gitlab version gitlab-ee=12.0.3-ee.0.

I am trying to spin up a docker container with the following run command:

```
docker run -i \
  --hostname gitlab2.michael-thompson.net \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --volume /docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
  --volume /docker/gitlab/log:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
  --volume /docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
  --net=bridge \
  --env TZ=Australia/Perth \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

The container boots for 20 seconds and then restarts (and continues in a never ending loop). Everything seems to run well until Gitlab attempts to "migrate" the database, and spits out the following error:

```
Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations
  * bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] action run
    [execute] rake aborted!
              StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

              PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
              : CREATE TABLE "audit_events" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "author_id" integer NOT NULL, "type" character varying NOT NULL, "entity_id" integer NOT NULL, "entity_type" character varying NOT NULL, "details" text, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

              Caused by:
              ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
              : CREATE TABLE "audit_events" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "author_id" integer NOT NULL, "type" character varying NOT NULL, "entity_id" integer NOT NULL, "entity_type" character varying NOT NULL, "details" text, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

              Caused by:
              PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
              Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
              (See full trace by running task with --trace)
              == 20141118150935 AddAuditEvent: migrating ====================================
              -- adapter_name()
                 -> 0.0000s
              -- adapter_name()
                 -> 0.0000s
              -- create_table(:audit_events, {:id=>:integer})

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20190704-26-1gi3jcd" ----
    STDOUT: rake aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
    : CREATE TABLE "audit_events" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "author_id" integer NOT NULL, "type" character varying NOT NULL, "entity_id" integer NOT NULL, "entity_type" character varying NOT NULL, "details" text, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

    Caused by:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
    : CREATE TABLE "audit_events" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "author_id" integer NOT NULL, "type" character varying NOT NULL, "entity_id" integer NOT NULL, "entity_type" character varying NOT NULL, "details" text, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

    Caused by:
    PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20141118150935_add_audit_event.rb:6:in `change'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    == 20141118150935 AddAuditEvent: migrating ====================================
    -- adapter_name()
       -> 0.0000s
    -- adapter_name()
       -> 0.0000s
    -- create_table(:audit_events, {:id=>:integer})
    STDERR:
    ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20190704-26-1gi3jcd" ----
    Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20190704-26-1gi3jcd" returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb

     53: bash "migrate gitlab-rails database" do
     54:   code <<-EOH
     55:     set -e
     56:     log_file="#{node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['log_directory']}/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log"
     57:     umask 077
     58:     /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}
     59:     STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
     60:     echo $STATUS > #{db_migrate_status_file}
     61:     exit $STATUS
     62:   EOH
     63:   environment env_variables unless env_variables.empty?
     64:   notifies :run, "execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]", :immediately
     65:   dependent_services.each do |svc|
     66:     notifies :restart, svc, :immediately
     67:   end
     68:   not_if "(test -f #{db_migrate_status_file}) && (cat #{db_migrate_status_file} | grep -Fx 0)"
     69:   only_if { node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['auto_migrate'] }
     70: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb:53:in `from_file'

    bash("migrate gitlab-rails database") do
      action [:run]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command nil
      backup 5
      returns 0
      user nil
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "database_migrations"
      code "    set -e\n    log_file=\"/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log\"\n    umask 077\n    /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}\n    STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}\n    echo $STATUS > /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-1b1872f9d93\n    exit $STATUS\n"
      domain nil
      not_if "(test -f /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-1b1872f9d93) && (cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-1b1872f9d93 | grep -Fx 0)"
      only_if { #code block }
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.6.4
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=16.04
    ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client

Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action run
```

I've spent the best part of a day on this and can't figure out why it is crashing. I'm not using an external database engine / container, so I expect that that should be brand new with my container, and don't understand how it could be that the table already exists.

I have run the suggested `docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions` however given my suspicions it is database related, I had low hopes to which I seemed to be correct when trying to start the container again.

I have also tried updating my system via apt (with no luck, to no surprise), stopping and starting my container, to find the same error. I am already running 2 docker containers at this very moment on the same box, without a problem. I am also running another instance of Gitlab elsewhere (not inside a container) with the same config (although tweaked for the new system), also without a problem. It was my intention to migrate into the docker Gitlab if I could get it working.

Thanks

Comment: gitlab-ee being a commercial edition, you should contact gitlab support for help.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I first installed Gitlab (previously, not as a docker container), it was ce. I did not knowingly upgrade to ee and am not paying for enterprise support, and according to the license model I read up on yesterday, it is OK to run ee without paying, and it will continue to operate in the same manner as ce. The reason I am installing ee is so that I can import my backup from my current production gitlab.

In short, I do not have enterprise support for this as I am not a paying customer.

Comment: According to the error message, the DB content (within /var/opt/gitlab) is proabbly corrupted, the state of the DB doesn't match the recorded state of migration tasks, you should restore a backup before retrying

Comment: This is on the initial boot of the container. It is automatically trying to run the initial database migration. I do have a backup which I wish to restore into, but I need gitlab to be initialised before I can do that.

Comment: You are mounting /var/opt/gitlab as a volume from the host, so there's obviously something broken in those datas, just empty it to restart from scratch

Comment: Quite right! I made sure to go all out and cleared /var/opt/gitlab, removed the container and re-did the config again. When I did this, I inspected the boot and it did indeed boot up and run first time. If you would like to move this comment to an answer, I will mark it as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message

> PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "audit_events" already exists

The DB content (within `/var/opt/gitlab`) is probably corrupted, the state of the DB doesn't match the recorded state of migration tasks.

As you're mounting `/var/opt/gitlab` as a volume from the host with `--volume /docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z`, there's obviously something broken in those datas. you should just empty it to restart from scratch and restore a backup once bootstrapped properly.